# Christoffel Symbols and the change of transformation law.

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I have seen it written that the change of co-ordinate form is given by the following:

$$ \tilde \Gamma^{i}_{jk} = {\partial \tilde x^i \over \partial x^\alpha} \left [ \Gamma^\alpha_{\beta \gamma}{\partial x^\beta \over \partial \tilde x^i}{\partial x^\gamma \over \partial \tilde x^k} + {\partial ^2 x^\alpha \over \partial \tilde x^j \partial \tilde x^k} \right ]$$

I am at a loose end as to how to prove this though. I have seen a proof(which I have included below) but in particular I do not understand the second step. 
If someone could explain this second step, I would be very grateful!

Note : I would only like to see a proof involving co-ordinates. If you prove another way, please be sure to include some detail, as I will most likely be unfamiliar with it!

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 4):

I'll go over the proof you included one line at at time: The first equality just uses the definition of the covariant derivative. The second equality uses the assumption that $\nabla_i Y^j$ is a tensor; this is the standard transformation law for any (1,1) tensor under coordinate transformations. The next equality is a similar step. Since $Y^l$ transforms as a tensor too, the step here is to re-express $Y^\prime$ in terms of $Y$. Then it's just expansion of the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^m}$.

Comment: Okay. If it's a $(1,1)$ then I am happy. But why is it a $(1,1)$ tensor?

Comment: In principle that's by definition. The point of the covariant derivative is that it transforms as a tensor. So if $Y^l$ is a tensor $\partial_i Y^l$ is not and one defines $\nabla_i Y^l$ to fix this.

Comment: Could elaborate on how it is a (1,1) tensor though please. How is it acting on both a vector and covector?

Comment: By contraction with the indices. Given any vector $X^i$ and any covector $\omega_j$ you can consider maps $X^i \mapsto X^j (\nabla_j Y^i)$ and $\omega_j \mapsto \omega_i (\nabla_j Y^i)$.

If you're unhappy with this, do this: Since you're dealing with a Christoffel connection, use the definition in terms of the metric: $\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\kappa\lambda} (\partial_\mu g_{\lambda\nu} + \partial_\nu g_{\lambda\mu} - \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu})$. If you substitute the transformation behaviour of the metric, you find that of the connection.

Comment: To say again what I wrote earlier: Neither $\partial_i Y^j$ is a tensor, nor $\Gamma^j_{ik}Y^k$. Yet if you combine them to $\nabla_i Y^j$ the non-tensorial transformation properties from each part cancel and you are left with a tensor. Which is the point of the covariant derivative.

Comment: So just to confirm what is the value of $\nabla_jY^i(\omega,X)$?

Comment: $\omega_i X^j (\nabla_j Y^i)$.

Comment: It's just then our change of transformation would surely involve indices of the convector?

Comment: Which is why there are two terms with indices $i, j, p, q$ at the beginning of the second line of your proof. One of the "matrices" appearing there is for the vector index, the other for the convector index. Note that one of the $x^\prime$ is in the numerator and the other in the denominator. Same reason.

Comment: I.e for a $(1,1)$-tensor $T$. Then $T'^i_j\frac{\partial X^n}{\partial X'^i}\frac{\partial X'^j}{\partial X'^m} = T^n_m$?

Comment: Looks about right. It's maybe a good exercise to derive this yourself for vectors, though.

Comment: Wait. Is $(\nabla_i Y^j)' = $the second line with partial derivatives removed? (if you understand what I mean by that!)

Comment: This is what eludes me!

Comment: Not quite - the term in parentheses in the second line is $\nabla_p^\prime Y^{\prime q}$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, so maybe the answer is yes. In either case, it is as I wrote.

Comment: Argh that is was I thought it should be. I am still lost then.

Comment: I don't understand because if when substitute $T^i_j$ for $\nabla_iY^j$ then we do not arrive at our result.

Comment: Um. I'm a bit of a loss what else to say. Going from the first line to the second literally uses nothing but the definition of a (1,1) tensor which $\nabla_i Y^j$ is by definition. As I wrote before, if you're not happy with this proof, start from the definition of the Christoffel symbols in terms of the metric.

Comment: But $(\nabla_iY^j)' \neq \nabla_i'Y'^j$

Comment: I.e When we use transformation of tensors on $(\nabla_iY^j)$ we get taken to (partials)$\times (\nabla_iY^j)' \neq $(partials)$\times\nabla_i'Y'^j$

Comment: This is my issue. Do you understand my problem now? What am I missing?

Comment: I think there's your misunderstanding; the two things should be the same, unless you are using a notation I haven't seen yet. Maybe don't try to think about the symbols, and just realise that you have two tensors $Y$ and $\nabla Y$; one is (0,1) and one (1,1) and each can be expressed in two different coordinate systems. Whether you garnish your expressions with ${}^\prime$ or give them different names should not matter. In a nutshell, there should be an equal sign.

Comment: Okay thank you. You have been extremely helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The second line is wrong. 
At first act with the transformation of the covariant derivative $Y^{j'}_{,p}$. Then you will get 
$$\frac{\partial x'^p}{\partial x^i}(Y^{j'})=\frac{\partial x'^p}{\partial x^i}(\frac{\partial x^{j'}}{\partial x^q} Y^p_q).$$
So, you will get a term that will cancel the last term in last line in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

An a affine connection on a variety   $M$ is a map:
$$\nabla: \chi(M)\times \chi(M)\to \chi(M): (X, Y)\mapsto \nabla_XY$$
such that

$\nabla_{fX+gY}Z=f\nabla_XZ+g\nabla_YZ$.

$\nabla_{X}(Y+Z)=\nabla_XY+\nabla_XZ$.

$\nabla_{X}fY=X(f)\cdot Z+f\nabla_XZ$.

On a local chart with coordinate $x^1,\ldots x^m$  the  Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^k_{i,j}$ are defined by:

$$\Gamma^k_{i,j}\cdot e_k=\nabla_{e_i}e_j$$
where repeated indices are under summation and where  $e_i:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.
Let's consider another coordinate system  $x'^1,\ldots x'^m$ on the some open set,  then:

$\Gamma'^t_{r,s}\cdot e'_t=\nabla_{e'_r}e'_s$ where $e'_s:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^s}$, then:

$\Gamma'^t_{r,s}\cdot e'_t=\nabla_{e'_r}e'_s=\nabla_{(\partial x^i/\partial x'^r e_i)}\ \partial x^j/\partial x'^s e_j=$

$ \partial x^i/\partial x'^r[\nabla_{e_i}\ (\partial x^j/\partial x'^s e_j)]=
 \partial x^i/\partial x'^r[e_i(\partial x^j/\partial x'^s )\cdot e_j + \partial x^j/\partial x'^s \cdot\nabla_{e_i}\ (e_j)]=$

$  \partial x^i/\partial x'^r[\partial^2 x^j/\partial x'^s\partial x'^u\cdot\partial x'^u/\partial x^i\cdot e_j + \partial x^j/\partial x'^s \cdot\Gamma^k_{i,j}\cdot e_k]=$

$  \partial x^i/\partial x'^r[\partial^2 x^j/\partial x'^s\partial x'^u\cdot\partial x'^u/\partial x^i\cdot \partial x'^t/\partial x^j\cdot e'_t + \partial x^j/\partial x'^s \cdot\Gamma^k_{i,j}\cdot \partial x'^t/\partial x^k\cdot e'_t]=$

$  [\partial^2 x^j/\partial x'^s\partial x'^u\cdot\partial x'^u/\partial x^i\cdot \partial x^i/\partial x'^r \cdot \partial x'^t/\partial x^j + \Gamma^k_{i,j}\cdot \partial x'^t/\partial x^k\cdot \partial x^j/\partial x'^s \cdot \partial x^i/\partial x'^r]\cdot e'_t$=

$  [\partial^2 x^j/\partial x'^s\partial x'^r \cdot \partial x'^t/\partial x^j+ \Gamma^k_{i,j}\cdot \partial x'^t/\partial x^k\cdot \partial x^j/\partial x'^s \cdot \partial x^i/\partial x'^r]\cdot e'_t$

then $$\Gamma'^t_{r,s}= \partial^2 x^u/\partial x'^s\partial x'^r \cdot \partial x'^t/\partial x^u+ \Gamma^k_{i,j}\cdot \partial x'^t/\partial x^k\cdot \partial x^j/\partial x'^s \cdot \partial x^i/\partial x'^r$$

$$\partial x^v/\partial x'^t\cdot \Gamma'^t_{r,s}= \partial^2 x^v/\partial x'^s\partial x'^r + \Gamma^v_{i,j}\cdot  \partial x^j/\partial x'^s \cdot \partial x^i/\partial x'^r$$